# What's with having chicken or potato salad in the living room?

Tags: sentence-structure, culture

I came across the following exchange:

> Q: Warum machst du denn die Party nicht bei dir zu Hause?
>
> A: Darum habe ich ja noch nie eine richtige Party gemacht ... unsere Wohnung ist viel zu klein. Und überhaupt ... im Wohnzimmer mit Hähnchen und Kartoffelsalat? ... Ich will 'ne schicke Party.

So what's bad about having chicken or potato salad in the living room? It it a cultural thing?

And I would like to take this opportunity to ask about the construction of //*im Wohnzimmer mit Hähnchen und Kartoffelsalat?*// ... Could you please point out the implied verb to me? I mean the sentence must have a verb, but I don't know what it is or where it is...

Comment: Where did you find this exchange?

Comment: It is not a cultural thing, but a personal attitude.

Comment: This textbook appears to be the source: ["Zertifikat B1 neu. Übungsbuch"](https://shop.hueber.de/de/zertifikat-b1-neu-uebungsb-mp3-cd-978-3-19-041868-8.html). See [Übung 1/3 on p. 2](https://shop.hueber.de/media/hueber_dateien/Internet_Muster/Red1/9783190418688_Muster_2.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a specifically German thing. Maybe the food is. "Hähnchen und Kartoffelsalat" seem to be supposed to symbolize the kind of simple food that is normally made at (young people's) home parties when hosting a lot of guests.

Kartoffelsalat (and Nudelsalat) do have that stereotype attached to them. "Hähnchen" does not so much for me, but it's understandable nonetheless.

The "Wohnzimmer" situation is one where typically more people than there are chairs are standing and sitting everywhere in a room that is too small and not furnished for that purpose.

This person obviously doesn't like that and wants an actual venue for their party, like a club or a bar or a restaurant.

About the second question: It's not always possible to apply strict  grammar rules to spoken utterances, but here you can say that the implied verb for the "im Wohnzimmer [...]" part is the one of the question. The prepositional adds an interpretation to the question:

> Q: Warum machst du denn die Party nicht bei dir zu Hause?
> A: ... im Wohnzimmer mit Hähnchen und Kartoffelsalat? ... Ich will 'ne schicke Party.

"Und überhaupt" has the function of leading back to the question after the thoughts before it. The ellipsis (...) serves as a separator, because grammatically, "und überhaupt" is not part of the same sentence as the following prepositional. A colon ":" or dash "–" would serve that purpose better, but ellipses are often used in informal "written as if spoken" language to separate all kinds of grammatically incoherent parts.